# JS equivalent to .NET's MemoryStream.Read

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, byte

I need to convert this to JavaScript.

```
byte[] buff = new byte[6];
mem.Seek(..., 0);
mem.Read(buff, 0, ...);
```

So the AJAX needs to read .dat file from URL.
So through the loop I will slice the array in every iteration and try to access its members.
I want to convert **arraybuffer** to **Int32Array** and to to **basic array** so I can work with integers and do calculations for my app
Yes I did google solution but unfortunately I always get wrong array no matter what I did, JS just sucks when it comes to byte arrays.

Comment: You tagged this question `javascript` and `ajax` but none of this really appears in your question. You are asking for a .NET **equivalent**. The [MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) class **is** already in the .NET framework. And it has a method `ReadByte()`. Can you clarify your question? As it stands, it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Now I edited question, hopefully someone will come with a great idea to solve this out.